# How to write xml using StaxEventItemWriter with headers and footers

Tags: xml, spring, spring-batch

```
<testFile>
 <fileId>string</fileId>
 <fileDate>2008-09-29</fileDate>
 <fileTime>01:18:33</fileTime>
 <sourceSystemId>string</sourceSystemId>
 <Delivery>
  <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
   <deliveryOrder>
     <consumer>
     </consumer>
     <Data>
     </Datla>
   </deliveryOrder>
</Delivery>
<Delivery>
<!--1 or more repetitions:-->
  <deliveryOrder>
   <consumer>
   </consumer>
   <Data>
   </Datla>
  </deliveryOrder>
 <Delivery>
 <recordCount>2</recordCount>
</testFile>
```

using staxeventWriter i am able to write only deliveryOrder. How to add header fields fileId,sourceSystemId header fields I have tried header callback but I am not sure how to pass values to callback.

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: I think we can write a customWriter which inherit from staxeventWriter to fulfill your requirement

Comment: Please provide what you have tried?

Comment: I have created  a customWriter which inherit from staxeventWriter  and  overridden startDocument method.for footer i have used footer  callback

Comment: Did the solution work. Need Ideas on how to do this